# How to get the desired output from decoded json - PHP multidimensional array in wordpress?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I've been banging my head for days now and i'm hoping that someone far more intelligent than me (which isn't difficult as i'm a total novice) will be able to shed some light on my problem. 
I have json data being fed from different API's, the first API gives me the list of products and the route to each products individual API which I then use to get the data and decode it into a PHP multidimensional array in wordpress. I need to extract values in a particular order and add html formatting then return them into a string.

This is a simplified representation of my json feeds that have been decoded into an array, the first is the json i'm pulling the API address from:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "product": "Product A",
      "api": "some/api/feeda",
      "catagory": "some catagory"
    },
    {
      "product": "Product B",
      "api": "some/api/feedb",
      "catagory": "other catagory"
    }
  ]
}
```

The second is then retrieved and returns the product json:

```
{
  "data": {
    "title": "Product A",
    "catagory": "Catagory 1",
    "specifications": [
      {
        "detail": "Technical detail 1",
        "notes": "",
        "subDetails": [
          {
            "width": "A not so wide version",
            "height": "This one is shorter"
          },
          {
            "width": "a wider version",
            "height": "a taller version"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "detail": "Technical detail 2",
        "notes": "a little bit about detail 2 that is different"
      },
      {
        "detail": "Technical detail 3",
        "notes": "something boring to do with detail 3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My aim is to generate a post from only a selected catagory and populate it with a title and html formatted content pulled from "specifications" (notes and subDetails), so that the content of the post looks something like this:

```
<b>Technical detail 1</b>
A not so wide version
a wider version<br>
<b>Technical detail 2</b>
a little bit about detail 2 that is different<br>
<b>Technical detail 3</b>
something boring to do with detail 3<br>
```

Before I start creating a whole heap of posts I don't want with 'wp_insert_post' i'm using 'echo' just so I can see what results i'm getting. I got this far with the PHP and have managed to create a list with each products title, but nothing else I try works (I did manage to get a products specs in the list, but they were the wrong specs!)

```
    function product_list($productlist$) {
            $url_request = wp_remote_get('https://main/api/products/v1/all');
            if (is_wp_error($url_request)) {
                return false; // Bail early
            }
            $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($url_request);
            $url_json = json_decode($body, true);
            $url_data = $url_json['data'];
            if (!empty($url_data)) {
                foreach($product_url as $product) {
                    $singleproduct_url = $product["url"];
                    $singleproduct_urlrequest = wp_remote_get('https://main/api/products/v1'.$single_product_url.
                        '');
                    $singleproduct_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($singleproduct_urlrequest);
                    $singleproduct_json = json_decode($singleproduct_body, true);
                    $singleproduct_data = $singleproduct_json['data'];
                    $productspecs = $singleproduct_data['specifications'];
                    foreach($productspecs as $productspec) {
                        $specdetail = "<br>".$productspec["detail"];
                        $subdetails = $productspec['subDetails']
                        if (!empty($productspec['note'])) {
                            $productnote = $productspec['note'];
                        } else {
                            foreach($subdetails as $subdetail) {
                                $subdetailtext = $subdetails[width];
                            }
                        };

                        echo '<li>';
                        echo $singleproduct_data["title"];
                        echo $productnote;
                        echo '</li>';
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
                }
            }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: `$productlist$` is not a valid identifier. You loop over undefined variable `$product_url`. I'm not going to look any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried to solve your problem and came up with this function, I used your product json. please try it and let me know if it works for you.

```
$api_json = '{
  "data": [
    {
      "product": "Product A",
      "api": "some/api/feeda",
      "catagory": "some catagory"
    },
    {
      "product": "Product B",
      "api": "some/api/feedb",
      "catagory": "other catagory"
    }
  ]
}';

$product_json = '{
  "data": {
    "title": "Product A",
    "catagory": "Catagory 1",
    "specifications": [
      {
        "detail": "Technical detail 1",
        "notes": "",
        "subDetails": [
          {
            "width": "A not so wide version",
            "height": "This one is shorter"
          },
          {
            "width": "a wider version",
            "height": "a taller version"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "detail": "Technical detail 2",
        "notes": "a little bit about detail 2 that is different"
      },
      {
        "detail": "Technical detail 3",
        "notes": "something boring to do with detail 3"
      }
    ]
  }
}';

function generate_posts($product_json, $category){

    $product_arr = json_decode($product_json, true);

    if($product_arr['data']['catagory'] == $category){
        $result = '';
        foreach($product_arr['data']['specifications'] as $spec){
            $result .= "<b>{$spec['detail']}</b> \r\n";
            $result .= (!empty($spec['notes']) ? "{$spec['notes']}<br>\r\n" : "");
            if(!empty($spec['subDetails'])){
                foreach($spec['subDetails'] as $k=>$sub){
                    if($k == (count($spec['subDetails']) -1)){
                        $result .= "{$sub['width']}";
                    }else{
                        $result .= "{$sub['width']} \r\n";
                    }
                }
                $result .= "<br> \r\n";
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return false;
}

echo generate_posts($product_json, 'Catagory 1');
```

Output:

```
<b>Technical detail 1</b> 
A not so wide version 
a wider version<br> 
<b>Technical detail 2</b> 
a little bit about detail 2 that is different<br>
<b>Technical detail 3</b> 
something boring to do with detail 3<br>
```

You can call this function in your code after this line

```
$singleproduct_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($singleproduct_urlrequest);
$myProduct = generate_posts($singleproduct_body, $category); //use desired variables
```

If you need any more help let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I used your code and split the entire process into three functions. Works like a charm.